# Not able to call Stored procedure contains Varchar2_table as a parameter from Java

Tags: java, oracle10g, spring-jdbc

I am trying to write the java code for calling stored procedure using SimpleJdbcCall feature.
I am using Oracle 10g, Below is the procedure syntax need to call from our code

Stored Procedure Syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  ImportFile(
      enametab IN VARCHAR2_TABLE,
      saltab IN DBMS NUMBER_TABLE)
```

Stored procedure is accepting the Varchar2.TABLE type and Number_TABLE type, Which is type of Bulk SQL Types.
 I have tried below code from java to call the stored procedure.

Java Code

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)

                .withSchemaName("<<schemaName>>")
                .withProcedureName("ImportFile")
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("enametab", Types.ARRAY),
                        new SqlParameter("saltab", Types.ARRAY));//

        // Creating lists

        List<String> enameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        enameList.add("one");
        enameList.add("two");

        List<Integer> salList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        salList.add(1);
        salList.add(2);

        // Converting list into array
        String[] enameArray = enameList.toArray(new String[enameList.size()]);
        Integer[] salArray = salList.toArray(new Integer[enameList.size()]);

        MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        in.addValue("enametab", enameArray);
        in.addValue("sArchiveName", salArray);

        // Executing the stored procedure
        simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
```

After executing the above code I am getting error as

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.sql.ARRAY.toARRAY(ARRAY.java:238)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9152)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8739)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9229)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:4691)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:431)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:150)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreatorFactory$CallableStatementCreatorImpl.createCallableStatement(CallableStatementCreatorFactory.java:213)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1115)
        ... 8 more
```

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor` to create an `oracle.sql.ARRAY` that holds the data. In the ["Spring Data JDBC Extensions"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext) project we handle this in the [`SqlArrayValue`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext/blob/master/spring-data-oracle/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/support/oracle/SqlArrayValue.java#L90) class. You could either implement this functionality yourself or use the convenience classes provided by the "Spring Data JDBC Extensions" project. See the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html#orcl.datatypes.array).